# Add clicky tracking code to wordpress via functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I wan to add clicky analytics to my website using functions.php and I used the following but it's not working:

```
function my_custom_footer_output() {
  ?>
  <a title="Google Analytics Alternative" href="http://clicky.com/10091XXXX"><img alt="Google Analytics Alternative" src="//static.getclicky.com/media/links/badge.gif" border="0" /></a>
  <script src="//static.getclicky.com/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">try{ clicky.init(10091XXXX); }catch(e){}</script>
  <noscript><p><img alt="Clicky" width="1" height="1" src="//in.getclicky.com/10091XXXXns.gif" /></p></noscript>
  <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_footer_output', 99999 );
```

Comment: how can you say its not working ? did you try to debug `my_custom_footer_output` function ?

Comment: I tested that and I don't see analytics. I also used "Verify tracking code" by clicky and it says "Your tracking does NOT appear to be installed correctly"

Answer (score 0):

Update: For this to work, use this code:

```
function my_custom_head_output() {
  ?>
    ...code here...
  <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_head_output', 99999 );
```

In our case, it would be similar to the below:

```
function my_custom_head_output() {
  ?>
  <script async src="//static.getclicky.com/123456789.js"></script>
<noscript><p><img alt="Clicky" width="1" height="1" src="//in.getclicky.com/123456789ns.gif" /></p></noscript>
  <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_head_output', 99999 );
```

Credit: [Kory](https://theme.co/archive/forums/topic/clicky-code/)